# Are Channels wrappers over IO Stream?

Tags: java, io, stream, nio, channel

I want to know the distinction to clear the conceptual difference as I have been seeing `SocketChannel`, `FileChannel` etc. classes. compared to `Socket` and File I/O Streams

As I know, I/O Streams must be accessed sequentially i.e. they are a sequence of bytes which can be read and written to. You can also use Buffered Stream to increase efficiency of I/O as well.

So, compared to Streams, are "Channels" a totally new concept or just a wrapper over Streams?

Yes, If we say "Stream is a sequence of bytes" then what is a Channel in that sense if both are different?

Comment: Totally new. Hence the `nio` (or "new io"). IO Streams *might* be implemented on channels at some point, not the other way around.

Comment: No. They can't be. Streams don't have a non-blocking mode. They aren't asynchronously closeable. A stream write doesn't return a count. There aren't enough features in streams to implement all the features of NIO.

Answer (score 7):

Neither. Channels are not wrappers around streams (unless you explicitly wrap a stream via [`Channels.newChannel(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newChannel-java.io.InputStream-) or [`Channels.newChannel(OutputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newChannel-java.io.OutputStream-)) and they are not a “totally new concept”.

Depending on the particular type, a channel still represents a sequence of bytes that may be read or written sequentially. The fact that you can translate between these APIs via factory methods in the `Channels` class shows that there is a relationship.

But the NIO API addresses certain design issues which could not be fixed by refactoring the old stream classes (in a compatible way). E.g. the base types are interfaces now, which allows certain channels to implement multiple types, like `ReadableByteChannel` and `WritableByteChannel` at the same time. Further, there is no method for reading a single byte, which is a good way to get rid of the “You can use BufferedStream to increase efficiency” myth. If an insufficient buffer size is the cause of an I/O performance bottleneck, you solve it by providing a larger buffer in the first place, rather than wrapping a stream or channel into another, forcing it to copy all data between buffers. Consequently, there is no `BufferedChannel`.

Certain implementations like `FileChannel` offer additional methods allowing random access to the underlying resource, in addition to the sequential access. That way, you can use a uniform interface, instead of dealing with entirely different APIs, like with the `RandomAccessFile`/ `InputStream`/ `OutputStream` relationship.

Further, a lot of previously missing I/O features were added when NIO was introduced. Some of them could have been implemented atop the old classes without problems, but the designers clearly favored using the new API for all of them, where these features could be considered in the design right from the start.

But generally, as said, a channel isn’t an entirely new concept compared to streams.